# Code::Blocks - как убрать cc1: warning: option -std=c++XX is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, codeblocks

Если в проекте есть разные типы исходных файлов (C/C++), то возникает ошибка, если используется стандарт выше чем из версии установки gcc по умолчанию.

Ошибка примерна такая, безобидная, но вносит свои неудобства в процесс сборки.

`cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++XX’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C`

Способ избавиться от нее перенесен в ответ, по рекомендациям.

Comment: Если вы хотите написать вопрос и ответ на него, в вопросе укажите только вопрос, а ответ напишите как ответ. Кстати, на странице создания вопроса есть флажок для написания ответа на свой вопрос.

Comment: `The C17 programming language update is just a "bug fix version" to the C11 standard. C17 will soon go to ballot for voting and still might end up being known as C18, but for now the GNU Compiler Collection is getting prepped with patches as C17.` https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC-C17-Support-Coming

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь методом как избавится от этого warning.
Не все действия по устранению такого поведения предсказуемы.

- Заходим в `Properties` файла (например .c), выбираем вкладку `Дополнительно` и в нижнем окне пишем следующий код, для стандарта c17: `$compiler -std=c17 $options $includes -c $file -o $object`
- Заходим в `Проект` -> `Опции сборки` -> вкладка `Компиляторы`, правой кнопкой мыши вызываем контекстное меню.
- Выбираем `C - only flags`, добавляем `-std=c17`
- Выбираем `C++ - only flags`, добавляем `-std=c++17`

Порядок действий хоть и простой, но не интуитивно очевидный, ниже видео:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]